# To obtain the elementary symmetric polynomial in the binary finite field

Tags: finite-fields

Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in $GF(2^q)$. Let $b$ be a non-zero element of  $GF(2^q)$ such that
$b\not \in \{r,r^2,\cdots ,r^n\}$. Assume that $x_i=(1+ba^i)$ for $1\leq i \leq n$.

Now consider the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $n-1$ which is defined by 
$$
e_{n-1}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n})=\sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2<\cdots <j_{n-1} \leq n}x_{j_1}x_{j_2}\cdots x_{j_{n-1}}
$$

Question: How to show that $e_{n-1}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n})=1$?

I can prove that for $1\leq k \leq n-1$ we have $p_k(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n})=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^k=1$. 
But I don't know how to continue it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is odd and
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (Y-1-b a^i) = (Y-1)^n -b^n= \sum_{l=0}^n {n \choose l} Y^l (-1)^{n-
l} -  b^n$$

Comment: The elementary symmetric polynomials in the $1+ba^i$ are the coefficients of that polynomial

Comment: That's why we care of the elementary symmetric polynomials  in $x$ : they are the coefficients of the polynomial with roots $x_i$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Properties

Comment: Because it was impossible to guess you didn't know that